# Android: How to receive an http response in a new activity?

Tags: android, http, android-intent, android-activity, response

easy question: How do I receive a response (in my case send with Volley) in another activity?

MainActivity -> send request -> start new activity => NewActivity -> receive response

(I am a total beginner in Android App Developement)

Best regards!